# How to get Slider to show next or previous on span click

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm using a combination of bootstrap 3 and just writing from scratch.

When I click the image thumbnails, they do what they're supposed to do, but when I click the span arrows, it doesn't go to the next or previous image.

Here's the code:

```js
var maximages = 6;
var startpath = "imgs"
var extension = ".jpg"


function calcslide(x) {
    var currentimage = document.getElementById("bigpic").src;
    var dotat = currentimage.indexOf(extension);
    var stringnumber = currentimage.substr(dotat - 2, 2);
    var nextnum = parseInt(stringnumber) + x;
    if (nextnum < 1) {
        nextnum = maximages;
    }
    if (nextnum > maximages) {
        nextnum = 1;
    }
    var twodigitnum = ("0" + nextnum).slice(-2);
    var showimg = startpath + twodigitnum + extension;
    showbig(showimg);
}

function showbig(pic) {
    document.getElementById("bigpic").src = pic;
}
```

```css
.slider {
    text-align: center;
}

#bigpic {
    height: 500px;
}

.thumbs img {
    height: 100px;
    padding: 20px 0 20px 0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="slider">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left btn btn-lg" alt="previous" onclick="calcslide(-1)"></span>
                <img src="imgs/slider01.jpg" id="bigpic" />
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right btn btn-lg" alt="next" onclick="calcslide(1)"></span>
                <div class="thumbs">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left" alt="previous" onclick="calcslide(-1)"></span>
                    <img src="imgs/slider01.jpg" onclick="showbig(this.src)" />
                    <img src="imgs/slider02.jpg" onclick="showbig(this.src)" />
                    <img src="imgs/slider03.jpg" onclick="showbig(this.src)" />
                    <img src="imgs/slider04.jpg" onclick="showbig(this.src)" />
                    <img src="imgs/slider05.jpg" onclick="showbig(this.src)" />
                    <img src="imgs/slider06.jpg" onclick="showbig(this.src)" />
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right" alt="next" onclick="calcslide(1)"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slash `/` and a prefix is missing somewhere within your path construction.

Instead of:

```
 var showimg = startpath + twodigitnum + extension
```

I would try:

```
 var showimg = startpath + '/slider' + twodigitnum + extension
```